# Dictation tablet with Google Live Transcribe for hearing impaired

Tags: tablet, microphones, adaptive-technology

I'd like to find a solution for my grandpa who's severely hearing impaired to help him participating in the daily life. More specifically, I thought about an on-the-fly speech to text recognition with a very simple, large user interface on a tablet. Small enough to carry it around without bothering, but larger then a casual large mobile phone.

I thought about a tablet with a good microphone in combination with 
[Google Live Transcribe](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/02/real-time-continuous-transcription-with.html) because I was impressed how Google translate works nicely for on-the-fly translation which is built on the mentioned API. However I don't want to buy a random tablet just because of its screen but not able to catch multiple people in a room clearly because of a bad mic.

Do you have recommendations for hardware or software for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any tablet with a 3.5mm four-pole TRRS (tip-ring-ring-sleeve) jack (socket) for headphone will also accept an external microphone.

An external microphone will

- allow you to place the mic where it will work best
- allow you to move the microphone away from air ducts and other noise sources
- allow you to handle the tablet without thumps, scratches, and other noise conducted by the body of the tablet

Some microphones are [directional](https://www.zalmar.com/detail-YBS_Categories-Dictation-LFH9171.htm), to zero in on a particular person or group of persons; but even the cheapest external mic will almost always outperform a chassis mic.

You may want a [breakout cable](https://www.fullcompass.com/prod/528607-listen-technologies-la-436-ts-to-trtrs-mic-adapter) ([another one](http://www.alzodigital.com/products/alzo-smartphone-3-5mm-trrs-break-out-y-splitter-cord-w-stereo-mono-mic-adapter)) with the 3.5mm TRRS (tip-ring-ring-sleeve) [plug](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/2914/1528-2262-ND/7241507) to end in separate 3.5mm jacks for microphone plus earphone/headphone, if simultaneous earphone or headphone use is desired.